# Datepicker: Disable second + fourth week?

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have my days of the week picked out and it works fine, but am unsure of how to implement disabling the second and fourth week.

Looked at some other solutions, but it's disabling my datepicker.

```
$('#stp-datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "0",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        minDate: 0
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 6), ''];
    }
});
if ((week == 2 || week == 4) {
    result = [false, '']
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI Datepicker; Disable second and fourth saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850308/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-second-and-fourth-saturday)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried to copy some code from [this duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850308/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-second-and-fourth-saturday) but mangled it a bit.  The code you have here has several typos - an unmatched `)` in the week test, unmatched `}` at the end, and the whole `week` test and return should be be inside your `beforeShowDay` function.  You also didn't copy some key parts of that answer, so even fixing those problems your code won't work.

Note that if you only want Thursdays and Sundays to be selectable, inverting your test to check only those 2 days would be simpler to read, understand and write than testing every other day, ie:

```
if (day === 4 || day === 7)
```

is simpler to use than:

```
if (day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 6)
```

In any case, here's an updated version with the problems fixed:

```js
$('#stp-datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "0",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var result = [true, "open"];
        var day = date.getDay();
        var week = 0 | date.getDate() / 7;
        
        if (week == 2 || week == 4) {
            result = [false, "closed"]
            
        } else if (day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 6) {
            result = [false, "closed"]
        }
        
        return result;
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="stp-datepicker">
```